# How to shoot arrow in Box2d?

Tags: iphone, box2d

I am trying to shoot arrow with force in left to right direction on Touches Ended method.I applied linear impulse to B2Body, but it is not shooting in correct direction.
Here is my code

```
(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"ended");
//Add a new body/atlas sprite at the touched location
CGPoint location;
for( UITouch *touch in touches )
{
    location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

}

if (fabs(ccpDistance(startTouchPosition, location)) < 3) {
    return;
}

CGPoint diff = ccpSub(startTouchPosition, location);
diff = CGPointMake(-diff.x, -diff.y);
//CGFloat distanceX = bird.position.x - 50.0;
// CGFloat distanceY = bird.position.y - 160.0;

CGFloat velocityX = diff.x*-1/5;
CGFloat velocityY = diff.y*-1/5;

b2Vec2 birdVelocity = b2Vec2(velocityX,velocityY);

//make b2Body
CGFloat sphereX = arrow.position.x/PTM_RATIO;
CGFloat sphereY = arrow.position.y/PTM_RATIO;

b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.position.Set(sphereX,sphereY);
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;


int num = 6;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(-56.5f / PTM_RATIO, 0.8f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-51.9f / PTM_RATIO, -2.6f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(53.7f / PTM_RATIO, -2.2f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(58.7f / PTM_RATIO, 0.7f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(52.5f / PTM_RATIO, 3.0f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-55.0f / PTM_RATIO, 1.2f / PTM_RATIO)
};

b2PolygonShape polyShape;
polyShape.Set(verts, num);


b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;

fixtureDef.shape= &polyShape;
fixtureDef.density=4;
fixtureDef.restitution=0.1;
fixtureDef.friction=0.5;
b2Body * physicsBird = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

physicsBird->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
physicsBird->GetUserData();
arrow.rotation=atan2f(arrow.position.x-startTouchPosition.x,arrow.position.y-startTouchPosition.y)*180/M_PI +90;


direction = arrow.rotation;
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(direction, 24.8);
physicsBird->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, physicsBird->GetWorldCenter());
physicsBird->SetLinearDamping(0.4);
}
```

but it is not working.Please help!

Comment: How about just: b2Vec2 force = startTouchPosition - arrow.position;

Comment: This is giving error, invalid operands to binary expression cgpoint

Comment: But you get what I mean right? The force should be in the direction between those two locations.

Comment: yes I got it and I am very close to it. Thanks :)